# IBM Mobilefirst use java adapter in preview mode

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I create a java adapter and the java adapter is working fine. Path is

http://localhost:10080/ng2/adapters/Auth_SQL/users/aa/dd

however when I am calling the adapter from the application in preview mode Path visible in browser is:

http://localhost:10080/ng2/apps/services/preview/ng2/common/1.0/default/index.html?txbUserName=aa&txbPassword=dd

Please advise.

Comment: "Please advise" what?! What is the problem? Is it failing? How is it failing? What is the error you get on screen and in the devtools console of the browser? Is it also failing in a physical mobile device?

Answer (score 0):

Those are the expected fragments of a resource that resides in the MobileFirst Development Server. I see nothing out of the order there.

Was this your entire question? If not, rephrase it to an actual question.